# Changes doesn't take effect when i run Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Hai am starting my new BB Aplication. I tried to go with HelloBlackBerry. I ran it once succesfully and its working as it is meant. After running for first time i made a change like

```
public HelloBlackBerryScreen() {
    super( MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR );
    setTitle( "HelloBlackBerry its my first app" );
}
```

what i changed is that i added "its my first app". When i run the app as title it only shows HelloBlackBerry. What did i do wrong?.

Comment: Are you getting this issue in simulator or device?

Comment: in simulator. Could you tell how to exactly to run an app. Please

Comment: some times it happend like this Please delete deleverble folder from project and clean and build application with appropriate simulator

Comment: nope its not working. as u just said i deleted deliverables, cleaned project and build and then run

Comment: yes am using eclipse ide

Comment: i went through the book but not quite helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually some times it happend when old build is not clear in this case we need to follo these steps

1)Clean simulator (see bellow image )

2)Delete deliverables folder

3)Clean the project

4)Refresh the project

5)Build Project

it will work [image]with out any issues

Comment: This time it worked Thank You so much. I have been confused with this for last one hour.